# getting a specific part from a xml string

Tags: xml, string, vb.net

I need to get a specific part from a xml string in vb.net.

```
<![CDATA[<Report id="GDC_CO" version="5" timestamp="1537843272109">
  <Answer question="viaPlanning">
    <Value option="01" value="true"/>
  </Answer>
  <Answer question="infoFromTMS">
    <Value option="02" value="true"/>
  </Answer>
  <Answer question="trailerOK">
    <Value option="01" value="true"/>
  </Answer>
  <Answer question="trailerOK2">
    <Value option="01" value="true"/>
  </Answer>
  <Answer question="copyTrailer">
    <Value option="copyTrailer" value="1QDV832 "/>
  </Answer>
  <Answer question="trailer">
    <Value option="trailer" value="1QDV832 "/>
  </Answer>
  <Answer question="schade">
    <Value option="01" value="true"/>
  </Answer>
</Report>]]>
```

the part that i need is the value of value option="trailer".
so that means is that i need to get "QDV832 "

what is the most effecient way of getting that out of this?

Comment: have you tried anything yet? if you google "parse xml vb.net" you get plenty of results which might help you this is one example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/%2FArticles%2F4826%2FXML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET

Comment: @Markus the thing is that the xml is not in a file but in a string in my program wich recieves it from a soap call.

Comment: it doesn't mater, using LoadXml(string) on a string that is formated as a xml file works just fine, just get rid of the prefix <![CDATA[ and suffix >]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example

```
    Try

        Dim xmlString as String = "<Report> ... </Report>"
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString)
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Report/Answer/Value")

        For Each node In nodeList

            Dim optionAttribute As String = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("option").Value

            If optionAttribute.Equals("trailer") Then

                Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value)
                Exit For

            End If

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

    End Try
```